# Spring WebClient ignores baseUrl port number

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webclient

everyone!
I'm using Spring HTTP interfaces to communicate between my microservices, here's how i create such a HTTP interface

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduleConfig {
    private final LoadBalancedExchangeFilterFunction filterFunction;

    @Bean
    ScheduleClient scheduleClient(
            @Value("${schedule-service.base-url}") String baseUrl
    ) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .filter(filterFunction)
                .build();

        HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory =
                HttpServiceProxyFactory
                        .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
                        .build();

        return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(ScheduleClient.class);
    }
}
```

Then I'm testing this `ScheduleClient` using WireMock, so in test class I set up `baseUrl` like in the code below:

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void overrideScheduleServiceBaseUrl(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add(
            "schedule-service.base-url",
            () -> "http://localhost:9999");
}
```

After running test methods I get following output:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 

    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:337)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE from GET http://localhost/api/schedules [DefaultWebClient]
```

In the stacktrace we can find `http://localhost/api/schedules` so it looks like the port number has been removed from baseUrl.

What could be cause of such a problem?